# Reason for non-existence of pure Nash in Matching Pennies versus Prisoner's Dilemma

Tags: game-theory, proof-explanation, algorithmic-game-theory

I am reading some stuff on normal form game.

It is claimed that Matching Pennies do not have pure nash strategy because the strategy space $S$ is "non-convex", whereas Prisoner's Dilemma has a pure nash strategy

[image]

(Advanced Workshop And Tutorials On Operations Research (AWTOR-2012))

The strategy set for each case is:

$S = \{H, T\}$
 for MP, and $S = \{\text{defect}, \text{cooperate}\}$ in PD.

Let $H, \text{defect}  = 1, T, \text{cooperate} = 0$, then $S = \{0,1\}$ in each case...both of these sets are non-convex and more over every matrix game would have strategy set that is nonconvex. What am I not understanding and where does the non-convexity come in?

Comment: Your quote does not say that the Prisoner's Dilemma has a "convex" strategy space. (It does not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choices $\{0,1\}$ are called *pure strategies*. The set of pure strategies is not convex.

This set can be convexified by introducing *randomised strategies*, viewed as probability distributions over the pure strategies. In your simple example, this is equivalent to assuming that $T$ is played with probability $p$ and $H$ is played with probability $1-p$. The strategy set for $p$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$, which is convex.